# Script to generate N number of valid ip addresses?

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL and trying to learn by doing some simple scripting, I have taken upon to write a simple script which generates valid ip address from a given starting ip address.

I have managed to write one but have run into two problems,

1. The last octet has a zero getting added in front of the number that is 192.168.1.025
2. When i specify the starting ip something like this 250.250.5.1 it fails to generate proper ips,

Below is my code:

```
proc generate {start_addr total_addr} {
    if {$total_addr == 0} {return}
    regexp {([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)} $start_addr match a b c d
    set filename "output.txt"
    set fileId [open $filename "a"]
    puts $fileId $a$b$c$d
    close $fileId
    while {$a<255 && $b <255 && $c <255 && $d < 255 } {
        set d [expr {$d + 1}];
        set filename "output.txt"
        set fileId [open $filename "a"]
        puts $fileId $a$b$c$d
        close $fileId
        set total_addr [expr {$total_addr - 1}];
        if {$total_addr == 1} {return}
        if {$total_addr > 1 && $d == 255} {
            set c [expr {$c + 1}];
            set d 1
            set filename "output.txt"
            set fileId [open $filename "a"]
            puts $fileId $a$b$c$d
            close $fileId
            set total_addr [expr {$total_addr - 1}];
        }
        if {$total_addr > 1 && $c==255 && $d == 255} {
            set b [expr {$b + 1}];
            set c 1
            set d 1
            set filename "output.txt"
            set fileId [open $filename "a"]
            puts $fileId $a$b$c$d
            close $fileId
            set total_addr [expr {$total_addr - 1}];
        }
        if {$total_addr > 1 && $b == 255 && $c == 255 && $d == 255} {
            set a [expr {$a + 1}];
            set b 1
            set c 1
            set d 1
            set filename "output.txt"
            set fileId [open $filename "a"]
            puts $fileId $a$b$c$d
            close $fileId
            set total_addr [expr {$total_addr - 1}];
        }
    }
}


flush stdout
puts "Please enter the starting IPv4 address with . as delimiter EX: 1.1.1.1"
set start_addr [gets stdin]
regexp {([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)} $start_addr match a b c d
if {$a <= 255 & $b <= 255 & $c <= 255 & $d <= 255} {
    puts "this is a valid ip address"
} else {
    puts "this not a valid ip address"
}
flush stdout
puts "Please enter the total number of IPv4 address EX: 1000"
set total_addr [gets stdin]
set result [generate $start_addr $total_addr]
```

Comment: You might be interested in the tcllib ip package (http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/tcllib_ip.html) which helps with handling and manipulating IP addresses. Things get pretty easy with its `int2String` and `toInteger` methods.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing an IP address the *simple* way, it is better to use `scan`. If you know C's `sscanf()` function, Tcl's `scan` is very similar (in particular, `%d` matches a decimal number). Like that, we can do:

```
if {[scan $start_addr "%d.%d.%d.%d" a b c d] != 4} {
    error "some components of address are missing"
}
```

It's a good idea to throw an error when things go wrong. You can `catch` them later or just let the script exit, depending on what's right for you. (You still need to check the number range.)

More generally, there's a package in [Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/toc.html) that does IP address parsing. It is far more complete than you're likely to need, but it's there.

Second major thing that you should do? Factor out the code to append a string to a file. It's can be a short procedure, short enough that it is *obviously* right.

```
proc addAddress {filename address} {
    set fileId [open $filename "a"]
    puts $fileId $address
    close $fileId
}
```

Then you can replace:

```
        set filename "output.txt"
        set fileId [open $filename "a"]
        puts $fileId $a$b$c$d
        close $fileId
```

With:

```
       addAddress "output.txt" $a$b$c$d
```

Less to go wrong. Less noise. (Protip: consider `$a.$b.$c.$d` there.)

More seriously, your code is just really unlikely to work. It's too complicated. In particular, you should generate *one* address each time through the loop, and you should concentrate on how to advance the counters right. Using `incr` to add one to an integer is highly recommended too.

You might try something like this:

```
incr d
if {$d > 255} {
    set d 1
    incr c
}
if {$c > 255} {
    set c 1
    incr b
}
if {$b > 255} {
    set b 1
    incr a
}
if {$a > 255} {
    set a 1
}
```

But that's less than efficient. We can do better with this:

```
if {[incr d] > 255} {
    set d 1
    if {[incr c] > 255} {
        set c 1
        if {[incr b] > 255} {
            set b 1
            if {[incr a] > 255} {
                set a 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's better (though *actual* valid IP addresses have a wider range: you can have a `0` or two in the middle, such as in `127.0.0.1`…)

Answer (score 0):

### Splitting the address

Apart from using the `ip` package in Tcllib, there are a few ways to split up an IPv4 "dot-decimal" address and put the octet values into four variables. The one you used was

```
regexp {([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)} $start_addr match a b c d
```

This basically works, but there are a couple of problems with it. The first problem is that the address 1.234.1.234 will be split up as `1.` `234.` `1.` `234`, and then when you try to use the `incr` command on the first three variables you will get an error message (I suppose that's why you used `expr {$x + 1}` instead of `incr`). Instead, write

```
regexp {(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)} $start_addr match a b c d
```

This expression puts the dots outside the capturing parentheses and places integer values into the variables. It's also a good idea to use the shorthand `\d` (*decimal digit*) instead of the `[0-9]` sets. But you could also do this:

```
regexp -all -inline -- {\d+} $start_addr
```

where you simply ask `regexp` to collect all (`-all`) unbroken sequences of decimal digits and return them as a list (`-inline`). Since you get the result as a list, you then need to `lassign` (*list assign*) them into variables:

```
lassign [regexp -all -inline -- {\d+} $start_addr] a b c d
```

But if you can make do without a regular expression, you should. Donal suggested

```
scan $start_addr "%d.%d.%d.%d" a b c d
```

which is fine. Another way is to `split` the string at the dots:

```
lassign [split $start_addr .] a b c d
```

(again you get a list as the result and need to assign it to your variables in a second step).

### Checking the result

As Donal wrote, it's a good idea whenever you create data from user input (and in many other situations as well) to check that you did get what you expected to get. If you use an assigning `regexp` the command returns 1 or 0 depending on whether the matched succeeded or failed. This result can be plugged directly into an `if` invocation:

```
if {![regexp {(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)} $start_addr match a b c d]} {
    error "input data didn't match IPv4 dot-decimal notation"
}
```

Donal already gave an example of checking the result of `scan`. In this case you check against 4 since the command returns the number of successful matches it managed.

```
if {[scan $start_addr "%d.%d.%d.%d" a b c d] != 4} {
    error "input data didn't match IPv4 dot-decimal notation"
}
```

If you use either of the list-creating commands (inline `regexp` or `split`) you can check the list length of the result:

```
if {[llength [set result [split $start_addr .]]] == 4} {
    lassign $result a b c d
} else {
    error "input data didn't match IPv4 dot-decimal notation"
}
```

This check should be followed by checking all variables for octet values (0-255). One convenient way to do this is like this:

```
proc isoctet args {
    ::tcl::mathop::* {*}[lmap octet $args {expr {0 <= $octet && $octet <= 255}}]
}
```

(It's usually a good idea to break out tests as functions; it's practically the law* if you are using the tests in several places in your code.)

This command, `isoctet`, takes a number of values as arguments, lumping them together as a list in the special parameter `args`. The `lmap` command creates a new list with the same number of elements as the original list, where the value of each element is the result of applying the given script to the corresponding element in the original list. In this case, `lmap` produces a list of ones and zeros depending on whether the value was a true octet value or not. Example:

```
input list:  1 234 567 89
result list: 1   1   0  1
```

The resulting list is then expanded by `{*}` into individual arguments to the `::tcl::mathop::*` command, which multiplies them together. Why? Because if 1 and 0 can be taken as true and false values, the product of a list of ones and zeros happens to be exactly the same as the logical conjunction (AND, &&) of the same list.

```
result 1: 1 1 0 1
product : 0 (false)
result 2: 1 1 1 1
product : 1 (true)
```

So,

```
if {![isoctet $a $b $c $d]} {
    error "one of the values was outside the (0, 255) range"
}
```

### Generating new addresses

Possibly the least sexy way to generate a new address is to use a ready-made facility in Tcl: `binary`.

```
binary scan [binary format c* [list $a $b $c $d]] I n
```

This invocation first converts a list of integer values (while constraining them to octet size) to a bit string, and then interprets that bit string as a big-endian 32-bit integer (if your machine uses little-endian integers, you should use the conversion specifier `i` instead of `I`).

Increment the number. Wheee!

```
incr n
```

Convert it back to a list of 8-bit values:

```
binary scan [binary format I $n] c4 parts
```

The components of `parts` are now *signed* 8-bit integers, i.e. the highest value is 127, and the values that should be higher than 127 are now negative values. Convert the values to unsigned (0 - 255) values like this:

```
lassign [lmap part $parts {expr {$part & 0xff}}] a b c d
```

and join them up to a dot-decimal string like this:

```
set addr [join [list $a $b $c $d] .]
```

If you want more than one new address, repeat the process.

Documentation: [binary](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/binary.htm), [error](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/error.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [mathop](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

`lmap` is a Tcl 8.6 command. Pure-Tcl implementations for Tcl 8.4 and 8.5 [are available here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570).

*) If there were any laws. What you must learn is that these rules are no different than the rules of the Matrix. Some of them can be bent. Others can be broken.

Answer (score -1):

```
proc ip_add { ip add } {
    set re "^\\s*(\\d+)\.(\\d+)\.(\\d+)\.(\\d+)\\s*$"
    if [regexp $re $ip match a b c d] {
        set x [expr {(($a*256+$b)*256+$c)*256+$d+$add}]
        set d [expr {int(fmod($x,256))}]
        set x [expr {int($x/256)}]
        set c [expr {int(fmod($x,256))}]
        set x [expr {int($x/256)}]
        set b [expr {int(fmod($x,256))}]
        set x [expr {int($x/256)}]
        set a [expr {int(fmod($x,256))}]
        return "$a.$b.$c.$d"
    } else {
        puts stderr "invalid ip $ip"
        exit 1
    }
}

set res [ip_add "127.0.0.1" 512]
puts "res=$res"
```