# Add a number to ip address

Tags: list, tcl

I want to write a tcl program to add a number to a ip address like 192.168.255.254 +2 gives 192.169.0.0

```
#!/bin/tclsh
puts "Please enter a ip address"
gets stdin ip
puts "You have Entered Ip Address: $ip"
set Ip [split $ip .]
puts $Ip
```

Now i am facing problem in traversing the list. If i can traverse he list in reverse order then i can add that number and also forward the carry to left side and then print the new ip address with '.'.

I am interested in traversing the list in reverse order.

Comment: Curious on the arithmetic part of your attempted solution. Could you add it (including the "carry over") to the question? That would be a great start ... or do you ask instead how to traverse the "list" from the "right"? Please edit accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious as to _why_ you'd do this. Not all IP addresses are anything even _close_ to equal…

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712265/script-to-generate-n-number-of-valid-ip-addresses?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it:

```
package require ip
set ip [ip::toInteger 192.168.255.254]
# => 3232301054
ip::intToString [incr ip 2]
# => 192.169.0.0
```

Traversing a list in reverse order, OTOH, can be done using

```
foreach item [lreverse $items] {
    puts $item
}
```

or

```
lmap item [lreverse $items] {
    set item
}
```

(The latter example is equivalent to just `lreverse $items`; the point is that you can do all kinds of processing in the script part.)

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[ip (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.html),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lreverse](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreverse.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)